# How to move Keychain from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, keychain

I am trying to move keychain database from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion.

I can't find the place of keychain in Mountain Lion anymore.

Even if I will find that keychain file location:

1. Will it be enough just copy keychain database file?
2. Or is the database file from Snow Leopard not compatible with Mountain Lion?
3. How to move keychain database from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently both Keychain's files are in the same place in Both OS versions <sup>[1](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH7058)</sup> <sup>[2](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10941)</sup>. `~/Library/Keychains/`. Copying all the folder's content from one to another should do the trick.

Comment: Funny before I can't see that folder.. maybe it's because the installation was clean ? and nothing was saved in Keychain yet :)